# How to run a thin jar in docker container

Tags: java, docker, jar

This is the folder structure of the project

```
pom.xml
Dockerfile
src/
   main/java/com/example/*.java
   test/java/com/example/*.java
etc/
    config.properties
    args.params
target/
    app.jar
    app.tar.gz
    libs/
        //contains dependent jars
    classes/
        //contains compiled classes
```

The application is normally executed using this command:

```
java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dconfig.dir=./etc -Dlogback.configurationFile=./etc/log.xml -jar app.jar
```

I have written this dockerfile to run the jar in a docker:

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 6078
COPY target/ /
ADD target/app.tar.gz /
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-cp", "target/app.jar:target/app/libs/*:", "com.example.MainClass"]
CMD ["`cat etc/args.params`","-Dlogback.configurationFile=./etc/log/xml"]
```

But when I run the docker:

```
docker build -t app .
docker run app
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.MainClass
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Evaluations don't work on Docker commands. This way

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
CMD ["echo","My name is Tarun", "`date`"]
```

This will ouptut

```
My name is Tarun `date`
```

But if I change my `Dockerfile` to

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

CMD /bin/bash -c "echo My name is Tarun `date`"
```

Then you will get the correct output. So you need to execute your command using `/bin/bash -c "<full command>"`. Note the lasts parameter all goes in as a single parameter. In the array form it would be

```
CMD ["/bin/bash","-c", "echo My name is Tarun `date`"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your artifacts are not in `/target/` but in root directory.

Please refer to the [dockerfile document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy).

And the easiest way to find a fault in Dockerfile is running the container with just opening shell and doing what you wanted inside the shell. You can do this like below.

```
docker run -it --entrypoint=bash app
```